# Cannot Load Community Builder - Error Thrown

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

I'm doing some work on Lightning Components in a Developer Sandbox which is currently throwing an error. I have not done anything to my production site, no changesets, nothing. However, all of a sudden when I click on 'Builder' on my Community, I get the following error with the attached screenshot. The Community will load fine, if I visit its URL, I simply cannot access the Builder

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'last' of undefined throws at https://spacesift--sitestudio.na35.force.com/sfsites/sfservice/js?v=1.201701112040290929.en_US:41:24
```

[image]

Comment: Some kind of caching issue? Did you: try different browser | refresh cache | try anonymous browser window. This can help identify if that's the case.

Comment: It seems you are correct. It only happened within that specific browser, once I cleared the cache it was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Components aggressively caches Javascript. There appear to be cases where this creates conditions where JS objects that are expected to be there are not.

R&D are constantly looking for ways to improve this less than optimal experience at all levels of Lightning: in the core Aura framework, in specific implementations (app builder, process builder, community builder, etc.), and in the Lightning Component Framework that is developers are using.

A good first step when encountering an error like this is to flush the cache, try a different browser, or login with anonymous browsing to see if you are encountering a caching error.